# Can selectors be used with bind and trigger in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use selectors with trigger and bind in jQuery. Its a simple code and i can't seem to get it working :(.

Here is what i am doing.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

var ctrlChanged = jQuery.Event("CtrlChanged");

  //********** Any time a button with id*=btnAddNewEmailAddress is clicked, raise event that parent control has changed.
$('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').click(function () {
  $('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').trigger(ctrlChanged);
});
});
```

To subscribe to above event i am using following code.

```
$('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').bind('CtrlChanged', function(){alert('Control Changed')})
```

This combination is not working. When i click buttons with id matching "btnAddNew", i don't see alert message.

But if i replace [id *= "btnAddNew"] with something like

```
$('body').trigger('ctrlChanged')
```

then corresponding change in bind

```
$('body').bind('ctrlChanged', function(){alert('Control is changed'})
```

works like charm.

I am wondering if, trigger and bind works with selectors. I would think so... but they are not..

If yes then what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I think it's a problem with your selectors themselves. Do you have multiple buttons with the same ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change this:

```
$('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').click(function () {
  $('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').trigger(ctrlChanged);
});
```

to

```
$('[id *= "btnAddNew"]').click(function () {
  $(this).trigger(ctrlChanged);
});
```

You might also have to move the `ctrlChanged` event object to global scope; i.e. move it outside of the `$(document).ready()`, right before it would be good.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cory. That works.. but i was wondering if the events can be triggered for elements using selectors. I have over simplified the problem in the sample attached but in reality i am trying to solve problem where events are triggered by controls that can determined by selectors. Is it possible?

Comment: I just tested changing my code to raise events using selectors and it works fine. Thanks a lot Cory.

Comment: @CSC: I think it should definitely be possible.